# Remove local window menu bar in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

If you split a window so that it is no longer maximized, an additional menu bar will appear [below](https://imgur.com/a/fLMgL) the global menu bar. Is there any way to remove this menu bar?

I have a small screen and want to maximize my screen utilization.

Comment: That's just how Nautilus is. You can always try a different file manager like SpaceFM, etc. Cheers, Al